# favorites implementation mongoose express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to implement favorites future in my movie api, when the user visit movie-details page I want to check if this movie is on hers/his favorite list or not so the the button icon changes. Here is my favoriteModel

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const favoritSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    createdAt: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'Du måste ange användare'],
    },
    movie: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Movie',
      required: [true, 'Du måste ange filmen'],
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

favoritSchema.index({ movie: 1, user: -1 });

const Favorit = mongoose.model('Favorit', favoritSchema);

module.exports = Favorit;
```

I am not sure if it is smart to create a new collection for favorites but I thought that if I store the favorites on users document that the document will grow endless when the user adds a lot of movies to the favorites.

Then I want to check if the movie is added to the current logged in user so I know if I have to send a post or delete request next time the user clicks on the button.

I tried to create a virtual property on the movie document that stores rather the movie is on favorite list or not, but when I remove the movie from the list the virtual property will not change until i refresh the server.

```
movieSchema.pre(/^find/, async function () {
  const id = this._conditions._id;

  const added = await Favorit.find({ movie: id });

  movieSchema.virtual('addedToList').get(() => added.length > 0);
});
```